# What does being in a conda environment consist of, beyond paths? How are DLL dependencies resolved?

Tags: python, anaconda, dependencies, conda, environment

It in my experience so far it seems that basically directories such as Miniconda3/ , Miniconda3/envs/myenv/, Miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/site-packages/, and so on are added to the system path, enabling the python executable and other packages in myenv/ to be found.

I'm brought to this consideration by trying to "recreate" the conda environment within matlab (which unfortunately is blind to outside environment context).  Simply adding everything from `echo %PATH%` and python `sys.path` from a working conda environment to the path (`setenv('PATH', ...)`) in matlab does not do the trick in some cases, with one problem.  Within matlab, trying to call python to import torch by `py.importlib.import_module('torch')`:

```
Python Error: OSError: [WinError 127] The specified procedure could not be found. Error loading
"C:\Users\jsk\Miniconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\torch\lib\shm.dll" or one of its dependencies.
```

The DLL itself is present.  Its dependencies are not being found, I think because something is incomplete about my recreation of the conda environment.  Some other behavior is changed by `conda activate`?  Or there are some more paths added, that I don't know about by checking `echo %PATH%` and python `sys.path`?

Similarly, experimenting, if I'm in the wrong conda environment (both with torch installed), I can "cross-import" some DLLs, but others have dependency problems that are only resolved when being in the same conda environment as the attempted file location.

```
$ conda activate myenv2
$ python
>>> import ctypes
>>> Dll = ctypes.WinDLL("C:\\Users\\jsk\\Miniconda3\\envs\\myenv\\lib\\site-packages\\torch\\lib\\c10.dll")
```

works despite different environment,

```
>>> Dll = ctypes.WinDLL("C:\\Users\\jsk\\Miniconda3\\envs\\myenv\\lib\\site-packages\\torch\\lib\\shm.dll")
```

has the dependecy error again,

```
>>> Dll = ctypes.WinDLL("C:\\Users\\jsk\\Miniconda3\\envs\\myenv2\\lib\\site-packages\\torch\\lib\\shm.dll")
```

works because the correct conda environment is activated.

Similarly, I have tried dependency walker https://dependencywalker.com/ , adding all paths from a working conda environment to the "Module search order".  Many dependencies of shm.dll are indeed not found.  Something is still different between being in the conda environment and just being in a base environment to which all these paths are added.

Comment: I still don't understand how to recreate conda's dependency load order, but I was able to access pytorch and others from MATLAB by switching to OutOfProcess python environment.